# Validation error in aws cloudwatch events rule?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudtrail

I am triggering my codebuild using `codebuild triggers` feature with an cron expression `cron(*/2 * * * ? *)` which triggers for every 2 minutes . Unfortunately, this didn't run after 2 minutes when i checked the `cloudwatch show metrics` i can see that there were some `failedinvocations`. To know the cause the of the error i enabled the cloudtrail logs and i can see the error like this

```
 {
      "eventVersion": "1.04",
      "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "xx",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::xx:user/xx",
        "accountId": "xx",
        "accessKeyId": "xx",
        "userName": "xx",
        "sessionContext": {
          "attributes": {
            "mfaAuthenticated": "true",
            "creationDate": "2019-03-04T06:21:22Z"
          }
        },
        "invokedBy": "signin.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "eventTime": "2019-03-04T09:04:56Z",
      "eventSource": "monitoring.amazonaws.com",
      "eventName": "DescribeAlarms",
      "awsRegion": "ap-south-1",
      "sourceIPAddress": "xxx",
      "userAgent": "signin.amazonaws.com",
      "errorCode": "ValidationException",
      "errorMessage": "1 validation error detected: Value 'INVALID_FOR_SUMMARY' at 'stateValue' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [INSUFFICIENT_DATA, ALARM, OK]",
      "requestParameters": {
        "stateValue": "INVALID_FOR_SUMMARY"
      },
      "responseElements": null,
      "requestID": "94f3a789-3e5c-11e9-92f8-xxx",
      "eventID": "c9ecfca2-a650-4997-b707-xxx",
      "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
      "recipientAccountId": "xxx"
    }
```

What is this exactly mean `1 validation error detected: Value 'INVALID_FOR_SUMMARY' at 'stateValue' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [INSUFFICIENT_DATA, ALARM, OK]` ?

Does this error is the reason for not triggering my code build ?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do it from amazon command line, it looks like a known issue in AWS. I managed to update mine via the regular CI job of the orchestration.